# How to save time in database in timeformat in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

I have been trying for a while for saving time in my database in timeformat like `10:00:00`.

What I want is simply pick up time from `timepicker` and save `data(time)` in `timeformat`.

Here is what I have done:

- I have used `timepicker` as it gets data in format `10:52 AM`.
- I have used accessor methods to save time as follows:

  ```
  public function setRTimeAttribute($value)
  {
      $this->attributes['r_time'] = date('h:i:A', strtotime($value));
  }
  ```
- My post controller in case needed as follows:

  ```
  public function postSessionReservation(Request $request,$profile_slug)
  {
      $restaurant = Restaurant::where('slug_profile', $profile_slug)->select('name','ar_name','slug_profile','id')->firstOrFail();

      $this->validate($request,[
          'no_of_seats'=>'required',
          'r_date'=>'required',
          'r_time'=>'required',
          'restaurant_id'=>'required',
      ]);
      $data = [
          'no_of_seats'=>$request->no_of_seats,
          'r_date'=>$request->r_date,
          'r_time'=>$request->r_time,
          'restaurant_id'=>$request->restaurant_id
      ];
      $minutes = 1;

      Session::put('reservation',json_encode($data),$minutes);

      return redirect($restaurant->slug_profile.'/complete-reservation');
  }
  ```

But it saves the time as `12:00:00` each time.

I do not know how `12:00:00` is generated whenever I save the time. I tried a lot but could not figure out.

Hope you guys will help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this date('h:i:s', strtotime($value))

Comment: And what was the field type in database?

Comment: date('h:i;s;) also giving same 12:00:00 value in database.Field type is time in database@vijaykumar

Comment: i donot know where i get error .It should save data in timeformat.Could you please help me figure out this problem@vijaykumar

Comment: Add insert data code also?

Comment: $table->time('r_time'); This is the field of r_time in my database.

Comment: Reservation::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'restaurant_id' => $request->restaurant_id,
                'no_of_seats' => $request->no_of_seats,
                'r_date'=>$request->r_date,
                'r_time'=>$request->r_time,
                'status'=>'P'
            ]); this is how i save time @vijaykumar

Comment: Just print this print_r($request->all()) before create.

Comment: ok "r_time" => "10 : 52 AM" this is the format while i dd all request@vijaykumar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove spaces between time "10 : 52 AM" to "10:52 AM" and then change your line to this:

```
$this->attributes['r_time'] = date('H:i', strtotime( $value ));
```

This will surely help, I already tested it.

For example you can remove spaces through:

```
$a = '10 : 52 PM';
$x = preg_replace('/\s*:\s*/', ':', $a);
date("H:i", strtotime($x));
```

Comment: well how can i remove spaces there.Could you please elaborate it?i am using jquery timepeicker to get time @Ali

Comment: oh sry got your point.First i need to remove spaces.You really save my time.Thanks a lot @Ali

Comment: $string = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
        $this->attributes['r_time'] = date("h:i:s", strtotime( $string )); i did like this and works like charm.

Comment: Yes there is always one than more way to do things. Its up to us what we choose :).